# Lync 2013/S4B Client SDK - Cannot connect ContentSharingModality

Tags: c#, office365, lync-2013, lync-client-sdk, skype-for-business

I'm trying to follow along with this code sample from the Lync 2013 Client SDK documentation on MSDN (https://msdn.microsoft.com/EN-US/library/office/jj933060.aspx).

For some reason, I am never able to connect the ContentSharingModality in the Lync conversation - CanInvoke(ModalityAction.Connect) always returns false.

I am using an Office 365 Lync account, although I don't see a good reason why that should matter - if I use the same accounts logged into the Lync client normally, I can share the same content types with no problem, so I don't think it is a matter of permissions in Office 365.

Answer (score 0):

The ContentSharingModality modality can only be connected to in a conference call.  If you are trying to do it in a standard one-to-one call, that is the reason why it can't be connected.

You can start with a [conference call](https://msdn.microsoft.com/EN-US/library/office/jj933089.aspx), convert a Two-Party Conversation into a Conference all by adding a third [participant](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/microsoft.lync.model.conversation.conversation.addparticipant_di_3_uc_ocs14mreflyncwpf.aspx) or [Escalate](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/hh364908%28v=office.14%29.aspx) a Two-Party Conversation to a Conference.

Once you have a conference call, then you should be able to start the ContentSharingModality modality.

Comment: I think the problem is actually that I'm driving UI-Suppressed Lync clients, so there are bits I can't make use of due to limitations of running in that mode https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/jj933224.aspx.

Comment: I haven't done a lot of UI Suppressed mode apps. So you may be correct.  I have been able to join conferences in UI Suppressed mode without a problem but I have never tried to connect any of the modalities.